# Show all places in a distance by using postgres and sort them by the distance asc

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table :

```
create table place (
    id int not null primary key,  
    latitude double precision not null,
    longitude double precision not null,  
);
```

How can I get all the places which are not far than distanceZ to the point (X,Y) and sort the result asc?

I use this query:

```
select point(latitude,longitude)<@a>point(X,Y)
from place 
where point(latitude,longitude)<@a>point(X,Y) < distanceZ
order by point(latitude,longitude)<@a>point(X,Y)
```

is there anyway to do NOT repeat calc the distance 3 times and use alias or variable ?

Comment: The point data structure is defined as  Point(x,y). For geographies  `X corresponds to longitude and Y corresponds to latitude`. So you should have **Point(longitude, latitude)**. Also you may want to define the appropriate check constraints.  BTW the optimizer is smart enough to recognize your query uses the exact same calculation and will execute only once. However @SlavaRozhnev query seems easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

For prevent repeatable calculation you can use CTE (common table expression) in next way:

```
with distances as (
    select point(latitude,longitude)<->point(41, 2) distance from place
) 
select * from distances
where distance < 100
order by distance;
```

[SQL online editor](https://sqlize.online/sql/psql14/ca532a2aa06c2b1d518ce49c9470084f/)

Comment: Is this efficient? and will not execute the query tow times?